# Setting Up MobileFirst Dev Environment

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

OS: Windows 7
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160226-0632

Java JRE 7
Java jdk1.7.0_79

MobileFirst-8.0.0.0
IBM MobileFirst Studio Plugins 8.0.0.v20160803_2030

Greetings,

I am attempting to use Mobile First Studio plugin within Eclipse Mars to develop apps. Based on my research there is an embedded version of MobileFirst Server with the plugin. In the Eclipse Installation Details page I can see the IBM MobileFirst Studio Plugin. However, when working in Eclipse I am not able to see the MFP project option when clicking File>New.

I cannot remember if I installed these in the correct/recommended order and if that is contributing to the problem. Or could the problem be the use of Java 7 and MobileFirst 8.0?

Answer (score 2):

The MobileFirst 8.0 Studio Plugin does not include the server.

You need to have the MobileFirst CLI installed and server running before you can use this plugin. The plugin is depending on the CLI commands.

Please see this blogpost for additional information.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-mobilefirst-studio-8-0-plugin-for-eclipse-now-available/

Comment: Could you provide more information with regards to the MobileFirst CLI. It has been my understanding that the CLI tools are for non-Eclipse development. Since the MFP Studio tool (plugin) is built to work with Eclipse does this mean that the MFP CLI is only necessary when you are not using a supported version of Eclipse or a different IDE altogether?

Comment: Pre 8.0, the eclipse plugin included the server. Starting in 8.0, the plugin relies on the cli to run the commands so you still need to install the cli. `Eclipse plug-in is dependent on it to run its commands`. Can you run `mfpdev -v` in the commandline to ensure you have it?